# Setting the default (correct) profile for the Edge browser - for automated UI testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

I am unable to get my automated tests to start correctly due to a recent Edge browser update (the profile icon is now at the top-left corner).

For some reason the automated test (selenium based) is starting the browser using a profile that im not interested in. The right profile is configured as the browser's default. But for some reason running it as part of the automated test fails to load the right profile.

I've tried programmatically setting these edge options.

```
edgeOptions.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\{ME}\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data");
edgeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.name", "Work");
```

Unfortunately, after running with these options, the browser starts (with the right profile), but I end up with this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: Microsoft Edge
> failed to start: exited normally.   (session not created:
> DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
> msedge location C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so
> msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.) (SessionNotCreated)

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `edgeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.name", "Work");`? If you need to run with Edge Default profile, I think the first line of code is enough. Besides, you can end all the Edge processes in task manager then run the code to test again.